# Why is my DNS information replicating without Zone Transfers allowed?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

We have many servers at our business that have the DNS role installed on Windows Server (2003 - 2016). I have noticed recently that the DNS information is consistent among all our servers, which sounds good, but I have only seen that this should be happening when Zone Transfers are enabled in the Zone settings. Zone Transfers are not turned on for any of our servers, but the data still replicates to every server when one gets a change. Why is this?

I believe I saw on a forum post that, if the servers are also DCs, that the DNS information is part of AD and will be shared that way, but I'm not 100% on if that is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the General tab of the DNS server properties what is the replication type set to?

If it's set to Active Directory-Integrated then that's why.

[image]

Comment: To explain in detail: WIth this setting, the zones are stored and replicated using AD. There is no zone transfer as defined in the DNS protocol - it happens under the hood.

Comment: That would explain it, yes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Glad to help...